# Radiobutton value to EditText space

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

Hi guys I am trying to get it so the user will be able to pick units for a calculation.

I am just Radio buttons and I am trying to select a radiobutton, get the value of the string that is stored there and have that displayed.

So far i am getting my options to come up and when I got to Set he value that app crashes.

Any ideas or help would be great!

#### Java class

```
  public void Un()
    {

        Mq = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.u1);
        EditText c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.u1);
        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                show2();
            }
        });
    }
    public void show2() {

        final Dialog h = new Dialog(Sol.this);
        h.setTitle("Units");
        h.setContentView(R.layout.molunit);
        Button b1 = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        Button b2 = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.b2);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RadioGroup types = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioUnits);

                switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {

                    //  case R.id.M:
                    case R.id.M:
                        Mq.setText("M");
                      //  h.dismiss();


                    case R.id.mM:

                        Mq.setText("mM");
                       // h.dismiss();


                    case R.id.uM:
                        Mq.setText("M");
                       // h.dismiss();

                    case R.id.pM:


                        Mq.setText("M");
                      //  h.dismiss();

                    case R.id.cM:

                        Mq.setText("M");
                      //  h.dismiss();

                }

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                h.dismiss();
            }
        });
        h.show();
    }
```

#### Main.xml

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/u1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Text2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete" 
/>
```

#### Units.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioUnits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="@string/M"
        android:id="@+id/M"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/mM"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/mM"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/uM"
        android:id="@+id/uM"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/pM"
        android:id="@+id/pM"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/cM"
        android:id="@+id/cM"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"/>

</RadioGroup>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="133dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="77dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Logs I am getting this when i click on set (b1)

```
12-05 16:38:55.406      743-743/com.example.se414011.biochem1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.se414011.biochem1.Sol$8.onClick(Sol.java:262)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you attached the crash log

Answer (score 0):

**Edited after having more information**

Knowing `h.setContentView(R.layout.Units)` and

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
    ...
```

change

```
findViewById(R.id.radioUnits)
```

to

```
h.findViewById(R.id.radioUnits)
```

Explanation: `radioUnits` is in `units.xml` and is set to be the layout the dialog `h`.
`findViewById` without any object before it is looking in the Activity's layout which has `setContentView(R.layout.main)` which is missing the view `findViewById` is looking for.

Comment: Tried this but it did not work. The units.xml is just the layout for choosing the unit. u1 is in the main xml where all the java code points too. I have the same thing working for a number scroll wheel and it goes to the edit text just fine, i don't know why the radioubtton values will not just print out also.

Comment: Check `com.example.se414011.biochem1.Sol$8.onClick(Sol.java:262)`, it must have a variable which is `null`, from the code you posted it has to be `types` (is in units.xml) or `mQ` (not in units.xml).

Comment: Without knowing how your layout setup in your Activity's `onCreate` it's hard to help, what is your `setContentView`?

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
        //addListenerOnButton1();
        Weight();
        Req();
        Calc();

but I change it to h.setContentView(R.layout.Units); when pick the units